# Subtract as many likes from a list in Python

Tags: python

```
a=[["a","a"], ["a", "a"], ["b","b"], ["b","b"], ["c", "c", "c"]]

b=[["b","b"], ["a", "a"]]
```

the code should output something like

```
new_list=[["a", "a"], ["b","b"], ["c", "c", "c"]]
```

because this is what remains when we subtract b from a.

when I tried, usually the same ones were deleted completely.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: _when I tried_ Show us what you tried.  Otherwise we can only guess what you did wrong.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you tried with, then we can help you troubleshoot the issues you have.

Comment: Iterate over each item in `b`.  If that item exists in `a`, remove it.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: If you haven't taken the [tour] and read [ask], those would probably be good ideas. It can also be helpful to read up on what we expect of a [MRE] when debugging problems.

Answer (score -1):

So I'm gonna guess you tried something like

```
for element in a:
    if element in b:
        a.remove(element)
```

This has the problem that it will remove every single copy from `a` if it is found in `b`. Instead, you want to iterate over the elements in `b` so you only remove them once (or rather, however often they appear in `b`):

```
for element in b:
    if element in a:
        a.remove(element)
```

For the future: Please always include the code you have tried.

Comment: How can you “guess” what the OP tried?

Comment: Well he said the elements were getting deleted completely and that's some relatively simple code, which is also close to the correct answer, which would have that effect. As I said, it's a guess

Answer (score -1):

I tried @yagod's answer, but there is a problem: after removing an item, jumps over the next item (you need to remove the item from b to, and go back to the previous element):

```
i = 0
while i < len(a):
    try:
        del b[b.index(a[i])]
        del a[i]
        i -= 1
    except ValueError:
        # If a[i] not in b
        pass
    i += 1
```

@yagod, your code doesn't pass for example this test:

```
a=[["a","a"], ["a", "a"], ["a", "a"], ["b","b"], ["b","b"], ["c", "c", "c"]]
b=[["b","b"], ["a", "a"]]
```

With your code: `[['a', 'a'], ['b', 'b'], ['c', 'c', 'c']]`

Correct solution: `[['a', 'a'], ['a', 'a'], ['b', 'b'], ['c', 'c', 'c']]`

Comment: Are you sure you took the correct code? Because I get exactly what you have as your correct solution. Once again, you **do not** want to iterate over `a`. You want to iterate over `b` and check if it is in `a`